# Symfony Doctrine: Use of subquery with "HAVING" clause without using EXISTS

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In a Symfony project I'm trying to make a query with a calculated field. Simplify a lot my SQL would be something like that:

```
SELECT o.id, (p.price_a + p.price_b) as total_price
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN prices p
ON o.id = p.object_id
HAVING total_price > 10
```

My calculated field is more complex and use external values that change and I cannot pre-calculate it.

As I want only the distinct object.id I've added the upper code as a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o_id 
FROM (
  SELECT o.id as o_id, (p.price_a + p.price_b) as total_price
  FROM object o
  INNER JOIN price p
  ON o.id = p.object_id
  HAVING total_price > 10)
```

In Symfony I want that this query returns only the distinct "Object"s.

I've tried many options with query builder but I cannot add a subquery to the "FROM" clause.

I'm tryng to avoid using the inefficient EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.id 
FROM objects o
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT p.*, (p.price_a + p.price_b) as total_price
  FROM prices p
  WHERE o.id = p.object_id
  HAVING total_price > 10)
```

Is there any way to do this with Query Builder without using "EXISTS"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem thanks to the HIDDEN keyword. With HIDDEN you can mark a field to avoid the ORM fetching. It's perfect to remove calculated fields.

With DQL:

```
SELECT o, (p.price_a + p.price_b) AS HIDDEN total_price
FROM TestObjectBundle:Object o
INNER JOIN TestObjectBuncle:Price p
GROUP BY o
HAVING total_price > 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately HIDDEN will not work when used inside an IN subquery. Please refer to my example: gist.github.com/webdevilopers/aa6a0ea06d7b5d4f0b04